# Why Dot Notation For "Method" Variables and Not For Others?

Tags: class, python-2.7, methods, attributes

Let's say I create the following class in Python:

```
class SomeClass(object):
    variable_1 = "Something"
    def __init__(self, variable_2):
        self.variable_2 = variable_2 + self.variable_1
```

I do not understand why variables lying outside the method (should I say function?) definition, but inside the body of class, are not named using the dot notation like `variable_1`, and variables inside the method definition are named - for example: `self.variable_2` - or referenced - for example: `self.variable_1` using the dot notation. Is this just a notation specific to Python or is this for some other reason?

Answer (score 1):

It is not something you will find in C++ or java. It is not only a notation. See the documentation [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html):

> classes partake of the dynamic nature of Python: they are created at
>   runtime, and can be modified further after creation.

And it is the same for functions.

Here is a valid way to define a class:

```
def f1(self, x, y):
    return min(x, x+y)

class C:
    text = 'hello world'
    f = f1
    def g(self):
        return self.text
    h = g
```

`f`, `g`and `h`are attributes of `C`. To make it work, it is important to pass the object as an argument of the functions. By convention, it is named `self`.

This is very powerful. It allows to really use a function as an attribute. For example:

```
c = C()
class B:
    text = 'hello word 2'
    g = c.g
```

The call to `B.g()` will return `'hello word 2'`. It is only possible because of the use of `self`.

For the record, you may also read the documentation of `global` and of the variable scope in general.